# Как можно изменять порядок элементов массива из DOM?

Tags: javascript

У меня в реакт компоненте, рендерется определенный список из массива с помощью map(). 
Соответственно в DOM они отображаются последовательно, соответсвтенно порядку элементов в массиве. 
Возник вопрос, можно ли менять элемент массива местами, меняя их последовательность в дом, например с помощью драгдроп. 
Такое возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Как то так?

```js
let elements = ['red','green','blue','cyan','magenta'];

document.body.innerHTML = elements.map(e => 
  `<div style='color:${e}' data-value='${e}' class='draggable'>${e}</div>`).join('');

document.querySelectorAll('.draggable').forEach(e => {
  e.draggable = true;
  e.ondragstart = e => e.dataTransfer
    .setData("value", e.target.dataset.value);
  e.ondragover = e => {
    upd();
    e.target.classList.add('over');
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  e.ondrop = e => {
    upd();
    
    let fromEl = document.querySelector(`[data-value="${e.dataTransfer.getData('value')}"]`);
    let toEl = e.target;
    
    // move in array
    let arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.draggable'));
    let fromIndex = arr.indexOf(fromEl);
    let toIndex = arr.indexOf(toEl);
    let element = elements[fromIndex];
    elements.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    elements.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
    
    // move in dom
    e.target.after(fromEl); 
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(elements));
  };
})

function upd(){
    let old = document.querySelector('.over');
    old && old.classList.remove('over');
}
```

```css
.draggable {
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.over {
  background-color:  wheat;
}
```

Comment: последний элемент невозможно сдвинуть на самый вверх

Comment: @Demon__ANT да, тут в логике ошибочка, наверное надо смотреть выше или ниже..

Comment: и что делает `e.target.after` ?Я не понял.Комментария `// move in dom` так себе.

Comment: @Demon__ANT это относительно новая фича https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after

Comment: спасибо и плюс конечно как всегда